# Non-monotonic DTS Errors in Concatenated FFmpeg Output with Multiple Streams

Tags: ffmpeg

I've encountered an issue while concatenating video files using FFmpeg, specifically when including multiple streams using the `-map 0` option. Here are the details:

I have two FFmpeg commands to trim the first three seconds of a video from a public sample:

1. Without `-map 0`:

   ```bash
   ffmpeg -i http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -t 3 output_t.mp4 -y
   ```
2. With `-map 0`:

   ```bash
   ffmpeg -y -i http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -map 0 -t 3 output_t.mp4
   ```

When using the output from the first command in a concat demuxer, everything works fine. However, using the output from the second command results in numerous "Non-monotonic DTS in output stream" errors and the final video's length is incorrect.

The whole process looks like

```
ffmpeg -y -i http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -map 0 -t 3 output_t.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -filter_complex '[0]trim=duration=3[s0];[0]atrim=duration=3[s1]' -map '[s0]' -map '[s1]' trim_atrim_duration.mp4
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -map 0 -c copy concat_demuxer.mp4
```

the body of files

```
file 'output_t.mp4'
file 'trim_atrim_duration.mp4'
```

Here are my questions:

Why does including `-map 0` (to include all streams) in the trimming process cause non-monotonic DTS errors when those segments are later used in a concat demuxer?

Any advice on how to diagnose and resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in understanding the underlying cause of the non-monotonic DTS errors and finding a reliable workflow for trimming and concatenating videos with multiple streams.

Thank you for your help!

I tried analysis the PTS & DTS to see if there is any difference between the w/o map output_t.mp4

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pkt_dts_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 output_t.mp4 > video_pts_dts.txt
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pkt_dts_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 output_t.mp4 > audio_pts_dts.txt
```

but didn't find any difference